# Optimised Dashboard and Publisher/Distributor design

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, database-design

We have a database that is not performing well and I am hoping to get some advice on the best way to re-design it. The database/application comes from a third-party vendor, and for the moment cannot be changed.

Currently we have a local distributor set up to serve about 80,000 reports per month of different complexities (I know - how complex or simple is each one - the number is more by way of indication than an actual load assessment).  We are pulling data from a number of different real time (x4) and transactional databases (x3) across a WAN on a minute by minute basis and then transforming that data into the schema.  We have dashboards (.NET installed client) and MSRS reporting.  There is also some minor data entry.

As you may have guessed, the server is struggling.

We are looking to move to SQL Server 2014.

There are two options we are considering:

- AG separation of Primary and active Secondary.
- Splitting Publisher and Distributor and using some form of replication (Transactional?) to push the data to the distributors.

Which would make more sense?

Also, each object on every dashboard calls its own query.  If 10 people from 3 different geographic locations are running the same dashboard, they will each be running the same query, and these will refresh every 2 mins.

Comment: Have you determined where your bottleneck is? Do you have a slow queries log? What database/version are you using presently? (You may wish to retag your question with a database technology).

Comment: The bottleneck appears to be at the server level.  It has 256Gb RAM and a very large CPU.  msdb is also getting hammered writing all changes.

Comment: The dashboard response times are terrible. We are using SQL Server 2008 currently.

Comment: OK, so what queries do you have on the dashboard? Have you timed each one? Please add examples of those queries to the question, using the code formatting tools.

Comment: Ah, now that I cannot do.  I am on the client side, trying to deal with a developed application.  That said, I think the direction here is getting a little lost.  I am not after specifics for this application, but a generic, optimised database architecture for this kind of application approach.

Comment: In that case, I think at the moment the problem is possibly too broad and vague. Are you just wanting to do high-level changes, e.g. replication, leader-follower configuration, sharding, etc? A full re-design would involve looking at your entity relationship diagram as it stands (and, as I outline, all of your top queries) and suggesting changes there. For that to happen, we'd need to see your database structure (and rough row counts for each table).

Comment: If you are only interested in server-level changes, my concern is that you could be wasting a great deal of money on extra hardware when it has not been established that some query or ERD optimisation would not help.

Comment: Hey halfer, I know exactly what you mean.  The trouble is, the software belongs to the vendor and we have no visibility at that level.  I too am concerned we'll consume any hardware we through at this thing...still, if we are confident the architecture is scalable to support the requirement, that then gives us an excuse to interrogate the vendor further.  Does that make sense?  Almost like a top down approach.  For example, Availability Groups are being touted as the saviour, but the intent of that design is HA, which we don't need...that's why I am going down the Publisher-Distributor route.

Comment: Ahh, right! That makes more sense  - I've made an edit to the question. OK, SQL Server is not my area, so let's see what comes in. Have you spoken to the vendor already? They should have timing devices on their main screens (e.g. if this is a web app, they should be able to see frontend rendering times in something like New Relic). Perhaps they should look into optimising things before you try scaling out?